# Django Relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

What is the best way to model something like this in Django?

[image]

1)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

This leads to a OneToMany and a ManyToOne Relationship

2)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.OneToOneField("Author", related_name="author")


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

This leads to a OneToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne Relationship (with an unesecary ManyToOne Relationship)

3)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.OneToOneField("Author", related_name="+")


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="+")
```

This is the closest what i want, but is there any better way?

€dit: Author -> Book should be 1; *, not 0; * but not relevant for this question

---

UPDATE:

That worked for me:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through="AuthorBook")


class AuthorBook(models.Model):
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Thank you @giaco

Comment: totally depend on your application requirements

Comment: Your diagram is unclear. The first option is the correct way to modern this relationship. Why do you want an extra one-to-one?

Comment: In words:

One Book depends to exact one Author (OneToOne)

One Author has one to n Books (OneToMany)

The first solution creates a OneToMany Relationship from the Author side and a ManyToOne Relationship from the Book side

Comment: Book and Author is ManyToMany relationship while book can have more then one authors and author can write more then one book. Therefore you need table AuthorBook in which you have records with Book and Author ids.

Comment: Just did it. You're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book and Author is ManyToMany relationship while book can have more then one authors and author can write more then one book. Therefore you need table AuthorBook in which you have records with Book and Author ids

Answer (score 1):

You should have an [intermediary model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models) between author and book:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='AuthorBook')

class AuthorBook(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you, that comes realy close to what i needed, but @giaco was a bit quicker :)